# Sum of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $v_1,v_2...v_n$ are eigenvectors of an $n\times n$ matrix, is it possible to find $\sum_{i=0}^{n} v_i$ without explicitly finding the eigen vectors?

All the vectors are normalized to 1 and $+1$ or $-1$ in front of it doesn't matter.

It is most probably not possible. I couldn't derive any expression and also couldn't find anything online. So, is it possible?

Comment: What are you given? If you are given $v_1,\dots,v_n$, then of course it's possible. If you are just given the matrix, then it's possible to find the eigenvectors (at least, numerically), so again it's possible to find the sum. So, what are you really asking?

Comment: I am given a matrix. I want to find the sum of eigenvectors without explicitly finding the individual eigenvectors.

Comment: what is the rank of your matrix?

Comment: Since any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is again an eigenvector you can't know "the eigenvectors" when all you have is the matrix. So you can't know their sum. What do you need it for?

Comment: Note that an eigenvector is not unique. Each scalar multiple of it will be another eigenvector. For a fixed generic matrix, this sum can be anything (except zero).

Comment: @Ethan, note that Goobs has normalized the eigenvectors.

Comment: @Friedrich, note that Goobs has normalized the eigenvectors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then there are still $2^n$ possibilities for the sum.

Comment: @Friedrich, OK, so normalize it even more, by insisting the norm is 1 and the first component is positive. Then it's a well-defined problem (but I don't think there's any way to solve it that doesn't amount to finding the eigenvectors and adding them).

Comment: Do you know the rank of your matrix? Do the eigenvectors constitute a complete basis of the full space?

Comment: Yeah the eigen vectors constitute a complete basis

Comment: Any of those $2^n$ possibilities is O.K.

Comment: You need one more assumption to specify even normalized eigenvectors:: all the eigenvalues must have multiplicity one. With that assumption let's see if there's an answer to your question ...

Comment: You only know the matrix, right? Anything more? Is it, e.g., symmetric?

Comment: Assume that it is symmetric if it can't be done for a more general problem.